# Error in method invocation: Method encodeBase64() while calculating Hmac in Jmeter

Tags: jmeter, base64, sha256, hmac

I am trying to generate hmac as input of API request using below script in Jmeter :

```
import javax.crypto.Mac;
import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;
import java.security.InvalidKeyException;
import org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64;
import java.util.Base64;

String mobile="5000066639";
String name="Random ";
String email="random@gmail.com";
String dob="18041908";
String gender="M";
String pin="123456";
 
String CombinedKey = mobile+name+email+dob+gender+pin;

Mac mac = Mac.getInstance("HmacSHA256");
SecretKeySpec secretKeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(CombinedKey.getBytes(), "HmacSHA256");
mac.init(secretKeySpec);
byte[] digest = mac.doFinal(CombinedKey.getBytes());
String sigB64 = digest.encodeBase64().toString();
//Tried with below these 2 values as well but similar result
//String sigB64 = Base64.encodeBase64String(digest);   
//String sigB64 = Base64.encodeToString(digest);

vars.put("hmac",sigB64);
```

But getting the below error

```
Response message:javax.script.ScriptException: Sourced file: inline evaluation of: ``import javax.crypto.Mac; import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec; import java.sec . . . '' : Typed variable declaration : Error in method invocation: Method encodeBase64() not found in class'[B' : at Line: 20 : in file: inline evaluation of: ``import javax.crypto.Mac; import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec; import java.sec . . . '' : digest .encodeBase64 ( ) 
 in inline evaluation of: ``import javax.crypto.Mac; import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec; import java.sec . . . '' at line number 20
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just switch to `groovy` language

[image]

Don't be confused with `java` option from the dropdown, despite its name in reality it's [Beanshell](http://www.beanshell.org/) which has different syntax, certain limitations and worse performance, especially when it comes to cryptographic algorithms. More information:

- [JMeter Best Practices - Beanshell Scripting](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#bsh_scripting)
- [Apache Groovy - Why and How You Should Use It](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black)

Comment: Thanks Dmitri, this really saved my day!!